# iOS back button text disappears when clicking

Tags: ios, xamarin, uikit

In a iOS app develop with Xamarin the back button behaves strangely. Clicking on the text sometimes/rarely makes the text disappear. To go back to the previous screen, I have to click on the arrow:

[image: screen recording of the issue]

I also noticed that when just holding down on the text without releasing the mouse/finger, the text always dissappears:

[image: holding down]

Any clues what could cause such a behaviour? I don't think the fact that the app was created using Xamarin should play a significant role here - it's all native iOS view controllers and views.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the root cause. I was setting the font attributes in a theme on the `UIBarButtonItem.Appearance` proxy by creating new `UITextAttributes` :

```
var proxyUIBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.Appearance;
proxyUIBarButton.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes { Font = UIFont.FromName(RegularFontName, 20), TextColor = AtxBlue }, UIControlState.Normal);
```

It works when basing the attributes on the default attributes:

```
var attr = proxyUIBarButton.GetTitleTextAttributes(UIControlState.Application);
attr.Font = UIFont.FromName(RegularFontName, 20);
attr.TextColor = AtxBlue;
proxyUIBarButton.SetTitleTextAttributes(attr, UIControlState.Normal);
```

Hope this helps others with the same issue.